# Laravel get all records that are 19 days ahead of timestamp not firing

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to send a followup email to users using Laravel.

The conditions of the email are that any users that have a status of followup will get an email 19 days from when the recorded timestamp was added. I am doing this via a daily cronjob, but it doesnt seem to be firing and I think it is because of the query to get the users in the first place.

For example, if the date recorded is 02/12/2021, the email should be sent to them on 21/12/2021

The query is as follows;

```php
App\Users::query()
   ->where('status', 'followup')
   ->where('recorded', now()->addDays(19))
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding days,you should substract days from current date.
`now()->subDays(19)` instead of `now()->addDays(19)`

```
App\Users::query()
   ->where('status', 'followup')
   ->where('recorded', now()->subDays(19))
   ->get();
```

Comment: Wont that get records where its 19 days behind the current date? ... I need to find all records that are exactly 19 days ahead of the recorded timestamp

Comment: if i understood your question correctly then for example today date is 21/12/2021

 and cron run today then email should sent to all where timestamp recorded is  02/12/2021